# word length in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with understanding some of the codes in my assignment of finding the word lengths in a file. NB: the Environment I am using is Blue J with a library from dukelearntoprogram.com, this is the link for downloading Blue J, http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course3/index.php. I have created a void method called countWordLength, with parameter FileResource called resource, and an integer array called counts. this method should return the number words at a specific length in a file. For instance: 2 words of length 2: My as. 
They have given me the code for this assignment but I am not understanding the following code, in my countWordLength method.

```
for (String word : resource.words()) {
        int finalLength = 0;
        int totalLength = word.length();
        if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(0)) == false) {
            finalLength = totalLength-1;
        }
        else {
            finalLength = totalLength;
        }
        if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(totalLength-1)) == false && totalLength > 1) {
            finalLength = finalLength-1;
        }


        if (finalLength >= counts.length) {
            counts[counts.length-1] += 1;

        }
        else {
        counts[finalLength] += 1;
        }
```

The specific part that I don't understand is the meaning or usefulness of

```
if (finalLength >= counts.length) {
                counts[counts.length-1] += 1;

            }
            else {
            counts[finalLength] += 1;
            }
```

if my question is not clear, and you may want more parts of my code please let know. Any help
will be highly appreciated.

Comment: *I am having trouble with understanding some of the codes in my assignment of finding the word lengths in a file* Which codes are you having trouble understanding? And Blue J is not a good programming environment. Choose something else if possible.

Comment: BlueJ isn't really that bad, and it is easy for beginners to understand. And it includes a debugger, which @gatete yvon should be using to see how this code is working (or not).

Comment: As I see it, you're trying to check if the characters in word are letters or not. This would be easier if you would use a loop to check the characters of word.

Comment: The teacher, or whoever wrote this, has done the number one error programmers should never do: She or he did not add comments that explain what the code is doing and why. This should be your first and foremost lesson: always document what the goal of each method is, and how it does this. Now my guess: The "words" are actually sequences of non-space characters. The code checks if the first or last of these is a punctuation mark, and if so, deducts from the length, so that in `a "big" guy`, the `big` counts as three rather than five characters.

Comment: @NomadMaker Define [bad](http://bugs.bluej.org/issues/?filter=-5)?

Comment: It's designed for an educational setting rather than a professional setting. For starting out it's better than compiling from a command line. I haven't found any bugs in it.

Comment: @NomadMaker I've answered a lot of questions from people struggling with BlueJ specifically. And the questions usually start with something like: The following code is working fine in eclipse, but it breaks when I try and use it in BlueJ.... which is why I've started recommending they pick something else. I could care less what IDE people use, as long as it meets a certain minimum. VS Code, Netbeans, IntelliJ or eclipse are all perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

```
int finalLength = 0;
int totalLength = word.length();
if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(0)) == false) {
    finalLength = totalLength-1;
}
else {
    finalLength = totalLength;
}
```

> Above lines are initiating lengths. If 1st character is not alphabet, then reducing length.

```
if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(totalLength-1)) == false && totalLength > 1) {
    finalLength = finalLength-1;
}
```

> If last character is not alphabet, removing one more character but a special condition added here that it is we reduce word length only if it's length > 1

```
if (finalLength >= counts.length) {
        counts[counts.length-1] += 1;
}
```

> This might be bit tricky for you. If calculated length is greater than array we assigned, we are adding count to last one. Ex: Let's say they assigned array with 20 and if got word length as 30, then we will assign this word count to last index (19).

```
else {
    counts[finalLength] += 1;
}
```

> If length is less than size allowed than we will add to that respective index.